# Decoding a byte string from post request

Tags: python, post, decode

I am trying to decode a byte string in python but the formal `.decode('utf-8')` seems to be giving me an error. I am making a post request to a graphQL API. The template code is as follows:

```
 import requests
 hdict = #dictionary with relevant headers
 body = {'operationName' : opName, 'variables' : dictOfVariables, 'query' : graphQLQuery}
 resp = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=hdict)
 print(resp.content)
 # print(resp.text) gives an odd message
```

I am getting the following bytestr as a result of my post request, which is giving status 200.

```
 b'\x03\xb0\t\x00dY\x9a\xbe\xbe\x84\x8e\xe5\xe4$\x96P\xc7Xn^\x9d8\xe03\xcd\x19\xc7\xe3\x92\xfd\xff\xdf\xaf\x00g\xc0\x06\x07G\xf7xM\xe2z\xe7\xf1=\xf7\xd5vQT\xbf?\xb1\x91a\x15V\x81\x95&K\x0b\x08\x1f?\x10\xce6\xda\xe03\xd5\xf1\xb1 \xbc\x19\xc9\x17R\x95\xa5P\xde\xbf\x90/N\xfa1\xd0*<\x8a\x8e\xd6\xf1\xf3\xb6\x97\xf7\xadQ\xd5\x8b\x8b\x7f^\xc8\x1cm\x94g\xd1lW\xc9\x13*\x97\xf7\xa1\x92\xdf:\xf0Iy_~=[\xba\xa1\xdc\x17B\xbc\n\xf3\xd9\x8e\x10\xa2\xfe\xe5\xa8\xa5\xbb\xf5\xb0\xd9\x1e$\xdc\xe6^^\nq?l\x88/\xb7\xcb\x1d!n"\\5\xfer\x1b\xef\xc8Jj+ \x9aB\xae\xc3\x95\x90G\xeeB\xac\xe4Q.%EIkQ\xf2\xea\xe1\x8c\xe1\xcc\xda\xa2af\xa0Jj\xc1P\xb0\xb4J~\x91\xda\x9b\x86\xf22,I\xdeG\xcb\x9e\x9cW\x86*y\xc3\xc0\t\xa4\x87\x91UB\x7f\x15\xc0\x0b\xafJ\xd3a\xb7\x9d\xa2\xacd\x9e\x9f\x1d,\xf98\xc9\xfb\x8a(\xa9\x95\xbcm\x14\xce\xe5z\xb3]\xc3\x93\r\x9e\x1d\x87%LB\x11\xa4\x0e\xa6\xd0\xd2\xbdMJ\xcb\xfdGd\x03/\x1e=\xaf\x1c\x88Yq\xe0u\x7f\xd1\xb2\xf3\xac-i\xca(\x93\x95\xfc\xfbW)\x89\x9ce\xf9\xfe\x9c\xa6\xaf\xe7r\xa4\xcfCL\xf2\xea5\xf4\xc9\x1a\xf3\x12\x96\xed\x9c\xad\xfb\xe5(\x15\xc7\n\xbf\x0e\xf3\xf2b\xa0:"\x83\x93\xe5}\xfe6\xd2"\xe2 =!\x04\x90\xb42\xa3\x86E/\xee\xdd\x13\xea(\x96\xa0u\x08\xa6\x08\xd6\x02\x02\x82nHb\x16\xa4\xb68?o\xd3fS/0\xf5\x15\xd2\xf5\x8a\x9d\xa1\xbas\xf8S\x13\x9a\x90\xa7P\xc2\xff\xbc\x94\x12\x8bX\x11\x91QF\x85^\x83VS\xe0S= J\xc8\xc7I`?c7\xba\xd26K\xb9!|\x89\x9e\xe5\xde\xad\x92\xf1\n\xd7~\x01&\xf0\xa7&\x97\xfel\xe9\x1a\x06\xd2\x9d\x13\x86\xe5\xf1+\xbe\x14\xb1\x05c\x8d\x92\xd095\x9dF\x16\x8b\xbd\x85>\xa2%\x08\x1d\x92.\xdci\xad\xc10q\xc6\xb0\xc2\xf3\x13\xfa\xa9\x0f]<S\xad\x00\xaa;g\x06\xce\xcd\x92\xcbk$\xb2\xca\x98Y\x0e\x14\xd3\xaa\x99\xe8#\x8f\x981k\x13\x91\x8b\xd8\xe4/<\x19\xdd\xa7\x7fCZ\x06\xb7\xf1\x8e\x080X\x82\xef\xa1\xa9\xd2\x9d\xda\xb0\x0e\x13\xcbZY}\x9e\xe6m\xd3\x85^Y,\x85`\xa6{\x08Q\xa6\xac\'\xa4\xa2\t\xef\xfez\xa5\x1c4l\x028G\x07\x1a<Dl\xb4m\rs\x13\xdb\x16[1-\x9a\x9e\xcc\x8f\x14\x00\xee\x93\x90\xfdEb\xfb\xb5\x010\xceB4\xe4\x8cf\xc1f\x8f\xec\r\\\x1b\xe2\xbd{\xe7\x99\x06\xde\r_m\xcb 0\xf5\xa7\xe7d\xce\xa5\x19\x86\x86\x83\xe9N\xae&\xc0\xdc \xb1,"\x80\x030N\x80\x8cUsm\xeb%\x94\x18\xa6(|\xe3a\xa8CWS\xd1\x0e\xab;$\x06\xe3\xb97\x8c\xd0+\xc5F>\xe5\xe5\x99\xf2\xa1\xe5\x81\xba\xb3\xa7\xd0\xbc\x9c\x16c\x8e\x0c\x91G\xbc*\x14\xbbAP89FD\xfaIB\x1d\xa4\x94\xa0D\x80\xa5\x94\x95\xc6\xb3\xa3\x88\xdd\xeb\xc9\x80_H\x91U\t\x9f\xb3\xdd\xade\t\xfd_\x11\xdd\xb7\xc0u_o5g\\d\x8e\x06\x818\xa2mU\x1b\x83n\x1a\xcf\x1e \x19\x8dhT\xa0\xc1\xa9\xfe|`\x9aE\x86\x1f\xb9\xfd)\xf5\xc3t&\xf6\xe7\xb0N"n\x7f\x8b`\xdes\xfa\x86\x18Z\x96\xc7\xdf\xf9wB\xf3\x9c\x872\xc7\x91!^k\xbe\xdd"\x01i\x92(%v\xe4D\x88i\xfb\x0fu\xe1\xe40\x975\x11E\xa9\x04`\xddG\x10Vw\t\x92\xe3\xc6\x86\x18\x14B\x08>\xb5\x18\x93\xd7Md\x1d\x81\xbc1J4\x16\xd48\xa7\x1e&\x96\xcf*Q\xa4dE\xad\x82\xe2\xb1\xe2M\x87\xde\xe2\xbf\x1a/)\x1ctq+C\xd8\x7f\x8e\xbc\xd6aC\x9e5\x92==\xe7\xa1\r\xd3\x84(\xe7`\xbaS\xcc\x13`\xae\x938\x8e\xacf\xb6d\xfa\xfd\xed\xd4\xfea\x9d\xdb\x9c\xe2\xcb\x92\xae\xae\x0c\x03'
```

The `resp.text` is as follows:

```
 �dY�������$�P�Xn^�8�3�����߯ g�G�xM�z��=��vQT�?��aV��&K?�6��3�� ��R��P޿�/N�1�*<�������QՋ�^�m�g�lW�*�����:�Iy_~=[���B�
```

�َ��娥����$��^^��%LB���ҽMJ��Gd/=��Yq�uѲ�-i�(����W)��e������r��CL��5����휭��(��       ���UB��J�a����d��,�8���(���m��z�]Ó
���b�:"���}�6�"� =!��2��E/���(����nHb��8?o�fS/0�������s�S���P�����X�QF�^�VS�S= J��I`?c7��6K�!|���ޭ�� _m� 0���dΥ����N�&�� �,"�0N��Usm�%��(|�a�CWS��;$�7��+�F>���偺��м�c��G�*�AP89FD�IB���D����Ƴ����ɀ_H�U     ��ݭe    �_ݷ�u_o5g\d��8�mU�n� �hT����|`�E���)��t&�ӄ(�`�S�`��8��f�d�����a�ۜ�˒��(%v�D�i�u��0�5E�`�GVw        ��Ɔ>���Md��1J4�8�&��*Q�dE����M���/)tq+C����aC�5�==�

Is this some sort of special encoding, is this indecipherable, could I be blocked by the server? Is there any way to parse this message? Any help, suggestions, feedback would be appreciated

EDIT:
The headers of the response are as follows:

```
 {'Date': 'Mon, 31 Aug 2020 12:48:27 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding, Cookie', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'Set-Cookie': 'csrftoken=XU0msNH2ReQjvKWskc4Cy3KJZGWLRAx7jvS8FmAfYzKGI5ountLCTKSZ6818xDga; expires=Mon, 30 Aug 2021 12:48:27 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax; Secure', 'X-NewRelic-App-Data': 'PxQDU1JWCwETVlFbDwgEX0YdFGQHBDcQUQxLA1tMXV1dSn8UXwJHCwtYGE4hEVlDWDUtNF5UQFwCVEJQCjIMElkBS0AUCBgCHVAJVwVXB1tRDgZYVloJCxxVUFYCHRVWXAUFBARSVANUBwxRAAlREB8DWA1CBG4=', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload', 'CF-Cache-Status': 'DYNAMIC', 'cf-request-id': '04e628de7900000ca95187d200000001', 'Expect-CT': 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Server': 'cloudflare', 'CF-RAY': '5cb6ddaa5c240ca9-EWR', 'Content-Encoding': 'br'}
```

Comment: What is the content _supposed_ to be?  Is it supposed to be human-readable text?

Comment: I am supposed to get a json object back, but I am getting this junk instead

Comment: If you're expecting a json response, then you should be looking at `resp.json()`.

Comment: maybe your data is compressed ?

Comment: Also, it seems very odd that you're using `data=json.dumps(body)` in your request.  If the request is expecting plain form input then you would use `data=body`, and if it is expecting json input then you would use `json=body`.  The way you have it is a very odd mix of the two.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the response headers (`resp.headers`).

Comment: @snakecharmerb I have updated the post to include the headers of the post response

Comment: `'Content-Encoding': 'br'` -> the response is compressed with the brotli compression algorithm.  See the answer in the duplicate.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks alot, this gives me the desired result!